Calculating change in distribution in two cross-sectional survey years - calculating weights
I am trying to compare two cross-sectional survey years (e.g., 2001 and 2011) on the same variable. These are different, independent populations (this is NOT a longitudinal study; rather, two cross-sectional studies representative of the population). Survey weights have been calculated on several variables, including two age groups : 18-40 and 41-65.
Let's say that I would want to have 10-year age categories/groups in my quantile regression model, do I now need to recalculate the weights using these new 10-year groups for my results to be more accurate/representative or can I keep the original calculated weights?
Thank you
